# Call Javascript function with parameters from iOS ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, evaluatejavascript

I am trying to call Javascript function with params from iOS using 'evaluateJavascript', everything works fine but the params value is not being sent, please see the code below

```
-(void) callJavascriptFunc: (NSString*)val{
  //Example val is "Apple" string
  [self.webview evaluateJavascript:@"exampleFuncName(val, '\(someConstant)')" completionHandler: nil];
}
```

Javascript:

```
exampleFuncName(value1: string, value2: string){
   console.log("values == ", value1 + " , " + value2)
}
```

Console:
**ReferenceError: Can't find variable: val**

I am able to call the function but am not able to pass the variable.
Is there an issue with syntax while calling a function with evaluateJavascript

Note: *I have checked val has a value.*

Comment: What about `[self.webview evaluateJavascript:@"exampleFuncName('\(val)', '\(someConstant)')" completionHandler: nil];`

Comment: No it just gives the string val but not the actual value "Apple"

Comment: Ah, sorry. You're using Objective-C not swift. So what about: `NSString* script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"exampleFuncName(%@, '\(someConstant)')", val]; [self.webview evaluateJavascript:script completionHandler: nil];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a string containing the passed argument and use that as parameter for `evaluateJavascript`.
Like this:

```
-(void) callJavascriptFunc: (NSString*)val{
    NSString* script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"exampleFuncName('%@', '\(someConstant)')", val];
    [self.webview evaluateJavascript:script completionHandler: nil];
}
```

Depending on where the value of the parameter comes from, however, you should make sure that no code injection is possible!